# Mathematics Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

In Mathematical Induction there's something I'm not getting when proving p(k+1) is true Sometimes we just add k+1 to the equation as in

{ P(k)= 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2k−1)

P(k+1)= 1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2k−1) + **(2(k+1)−1)** }

and 
{ P(k)= 1^3+2^3+...+k^3

P(k+1)=1^3+2^3+...+k^3+**(k+1)^3** }

other times we just substitute k+1 in k like here 
{

P(k)= 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +(2k)^2

P(k+1)=1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +···+(2(k+1))^2 }

and here

{ p(K)= 1+4+7+···+(3k−2)

p(k+1)= 1+4+7+···+(3(k+1)−2) }

I hope anyone help me understand when and why we substitute K+1 or add K+1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first few examples, $P(k)$ is the sum of $k$ terms, so $P(k+1)$ is those $k$ terms plus one more. But with $P(k):=\sum_{j=1}^{2k}j^2$, the number of terms is $2k$, so $P(k+1)$ adds *two* terms. If you struggle with this kind of thing, ask yourself what $P(k+1)-P(k)$ should be by the definition of $P$. Calculating the result for small $k$ may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially doing the same in both situations.

Take the following function for example

$$f(k) = 1 + 2 + ... + k$$

When you take $f(k+1)$, you can write that down as

$$f(k+1) = 1 + 2 + ... + (k+1)$$

Notice that this is the same as

$$f(k+1) = 1 + 2 + ... + k + (k+1)$$

Because the ellipse sign (...) expands to a sum including k.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're just getting confused about what is hidden by the $\cdots$, try writing out one or two more terms after the dots, or better (but possibly harder) find and use an exact representation of the ecpressions.